# Can I check for null on a shared field outside of a synchronized block in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, synchronized

Let's say I have a field that can be accessed by two separate threads.  I'm using an Object for the synchronization lock.  Can I check for `null` outside of the synchronization block?  In other words, is this thread-safe:

```
private Object sharedObject() = new Object();
private final Object sharedObjectLock() = new Object();

private void awesomeMethod() {
   if(sharedObject != null) {
      synchronized(sharedObjectLock) {
         //code the uses sharedObject
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information given.  How else is `sharedObject` used in this class?  Furthermore, the code doesn't compile as originally written.  Are `sharedObject` and `sharedObjectLock` initialized when the object is constructed?  Or is `sharedObject` initialized later by another method?  Can `sharedObject` be set to null after it has been initialized with a non-null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The assignment of the variable could occur after you check but before you get the lock.

There was, at one time, a school of thought that synchronized locks were expensive, but that's not true anymore.  Just grab the lock.

Comment: Good point.  That school of thought was going through my head and I didn't want to grab the lock if the object was null.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not thread-safe. If another thread nullifies `sharedObject` field, your thread is not guaranteed to see that change.